# Creating script to report system suspend or awake is not running?

Tags: linux, bash, suspend

Here is the code that should output to a file when system goes into SUSPEND or AWAKES:

(this code is in /etc/pm/sleep.d)

(also had to make the file executable:  sudo chmod +x sleep_mode)

(when running from the command line, the "suspend script" is written to the file.

**(but when I suspend the computer or awaken the computer... nothing is written to file.)**
(16.04 LTS)

```
#!/bin/bash

# general entry 
echo "suspend script"
echo "%suspend script" >>  /tmp/suspend_time.txt
date +%s >>  /tmp/suspend_time.txt

case "$1" in
    suspend)
        # executed on suspend
        echo "%system_suspend" >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        date +%s >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        ;;
    resume) 
        # executed on resume
        echo "%system_resume" >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        date +%s >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what distribution you are running, but if you are running the `systemd` daemon, try putting it in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` instead (note that the arguments are different).

Script:

```sh
[eje@irenaeus ~]$ sudo cat /lib/systemd/system-sleep/95test 
[sudo] password for eje: 
#!/bin/bash

echo $(date) "$@" >> /tmp/args
```

Output:

```
Sun Dec 20 02:45:51 PM EST 2020 pre suspend
Sun Dec 20 02:45:59 PM EST 2020 post suspend
```